# navigationController is nil

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

At the root of my project's world I have a UIViewController *viewController declared in the project's app delegate. I'm trying to get to the view controllers navigationController field so that I can find the top ViewController. However, every time I look at the navigationController field of my viewController it's nil. Clearly I've forgotten to do something. Ideas? Thanks...

Comment: in the app delegate did you initialize a navigationController and then add viewController to it?  how are you currently switching views?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a strong property to your navigation controller. (Like Below:)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navcon;
```

Then synthesize it in your app delegate implementation file.

```
@synthesize navcon = _navcon;
```

And yes, then you can have:

```
self.navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
[self.window addSubview:self.navcon.view];
```

(Assuming you have ARC enabled)

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it the case that every UIViewController comes with a navigationController field and I wouldn't have to create a new UINavigationController?

Comment: @ron, your understanding is not correct -- it's true that view controllers have a navigationController property, but it only points to a navigation controller if there is one (it returns nil if the controller is not imbedded in a navigation controller). You need to create that nav controller like mvb said.

Comment: Ok, understand and have fixed that. Now I have the following issue. In this code segment


    HomeViewController *control = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"HomeView" bundle: nil];
    self.homeViewController = control;
    [self.view insertSubview:self.homeViewController.view atIndex:0];
    
    //UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: control];

things work as desired. But if I remove the comment that creates the navControl, the desired screen is not display. Ideas? Thanks...

Comment: @ron: The documentation might help you understand better about UIViews and thereafter view controllers: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html